# Display the contents of a text file in Linux 32-bit x86 assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

How do I display the contents of a text file in Linux 32-bit x86 assembly (NASM syntax)?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tested this (and it's not necessarily NASM syntax), but something along these lines ought to work on an x86 Linux machine:

```
; Open file 
mov ecx,0 ; FILEMODE_R
mov ebx,filePath
mov edx,01FFh
mov eax,5  ;__NR_open
int 80h  ; syscall
mov fileHandle,eax

...

; Read file data
mov ebx,fileHandle
mov ecx,buffer
mov edx,numBytesToRead
mov eax,3  ; __NR_read
int 80h

; Write to STDOUT
mov edx,numCharsToWrite
mov ecx,buffer
mov ebx,1  ; STDOUT
mov eax,4 ; __NR_write
int 80h

; Repeat as many times as necessary

; Close file
mov ebx,fileHandle
mov eax,6 ; __NR_close
int 80h
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as I misread the question. Before I did, Frank Kotler left the following comment on it (mistaking it for yours I guess): "Good answer, Michael! Only thing I would suggest is make sure the sys_open succeeds (eax > 0) before proceeding.."

Comment: @MathewHall: Right. I removed all the error checks in order to keep the code short. IRL one should of course assume that anything that can go wrong eventually will and check for errors.

Answer (score 2):

use this in the terminal like, *./[program name] > destination.txt < source.txt* , source being whatever file to copy from.... this will copy byte by byte.. if you don't specify a destination file this program will display the contents of your file to the terminal, *ie [program name] < source.txt* ...

```
    SECTION .bss
        fileBuf: resb 1
    SECTION .data
    SECTION .text
        global _start
    _start:

        nop

      read: mov eax, 3 ; sys_read
            mov ebx, 0 ; standard input
            mov ecx, fileBuf
            mov edx, 1
            int 80h
            cmp eax, 0 ; ensure havn't read eof
            je exit

      write:mov eax, 4 ; sys_write
            mov ebx, 1 ; standard output
            mov ecx, fileBuf
            mov edx, 1
            int 80h
            jmp read


     exit: mov eax, 1 ; wrap it up
           mov ebx, 0
           int 80h
```